# Wait on condition in Taskfile

Tags: taskfile

Is there a way to use a `precondition` in a Taskfile.yaml to wait for a condition to be true, before running `cmds`? (precondition makes the task fail, not wait)

For example, I would like to wait for a Kubernetes CRD to be fully available before running a task.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way there is right now, is to do

```
# ...
version: '3'
tasks:
  deploy:
    cmds:
    - task: await
      vars:
      - { CRD: "postgrescluster" }

  await:
    cmds:
    - |
      until kubectl wait --for condition=established --timeout=60s crd/{{.CRD}}; do \
        sleep 1; \
      done
```

As per https://taskfile.dev/usage/#task-dependencies